Could getting the front brakes and rotors done can that cause them to get bad again within 3 months?
Three months ago my brakes were bad and every time I turned the wheel, it made a screeching sound. I had to get brakes and rotors replaced. Due to finances, I had to just do the front set. Now 3 months later it’s doing it again. I still haven’t got my back brakes done. But my question is, is it because I didn’t change the back brakes or could it be my front brakes making that sound because they are already bad again? Please some insight please!! I don't know if it matters but it’s a 2012 Nissan versa.

You should bring your car back to the repair shop that did the front brakes and ask if they're faulty and/or tell you the rear brakes are causing the screeching. Brake repair should have a warranty.
